# how to stack a container inside or just below another container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, containers, material-design

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MainScreen());
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 250.0,
                width: width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(150),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(150),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Hello World",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontFamily: "Arial",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Hello World",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontFamily: "Arial",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 40,
                left: 20,
                child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  width: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### **I tried to add a new container based on same row but couldn't find how to stack with another container used positioned widget for the second container but didn't worked. after all made the first container same as second container using stack and positioned widget still didn't worked out**

*I tried to add a new container based on same row but couldn't find how to stack with another container used positioned widget for the second container but didn't worked. after all made the first container same as second container using stack and positioned widget still didn't worked out*

I uploaded a picture which contains two container together but not stack just at the bottom. Thank You.

Comment: Upload or mention the goal widget Image that you want, so we will know how could help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put two containers in stack, you dont need to create two stacks.
You just need to put two containers in a stack and wrap one of them with positioned.
Like this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MainScreen());
    }

    class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 250.0,
              width: width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(150),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(150),
              ),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Hello World",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontFamily: "Arial",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Text(
                "Hello World",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontFamily: "Arial",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 40,
        left: 20,
        child: Container(
          height: 500,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```